# Absolute Value Expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are the following expressions are equal?

$$\sqrt{x^2}=(\sqrt{x})^2=|x|$$

As there both are: $$x^\frac{2}{2}=x^1$$

Answer (score 1):

No.

$\sqrt{x^2}=(\sqrt{x})^2$ is not true.

Consider the domain of $\sqrt{x^2}$ are all real numbers, but $(\sqrt{x})^2$ is $x\geq 0$. So $\sqrt{x^2}\neq(\sqrt{x})^2$.

Comment: So for $0 /leq x$ it is true?

Comment: @gbox Yes, it is true when $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @gbox for $x\geq 0$ it is